# I would like my searchbox to stay Opacity: 100% when it's active

Tags: css

When I drag my cursor out of the top nav-bar the searchbox will become opacity:70% again. Would like it to stay opacity 100% once I've clicked the searchbox even if I drag my cursor out of it.

```
input[type="text"] {
border-radius: 25px;
height: 20px;}

input[type="text"]:focus {
border-radius: 25px;
height: 20px;
outline: none;
opacity: 100%;}

input[type="text"]:active {
opacity: 100%;}
```

Comment: Did you try setting the opacity directly for the searchbox? `input[type="text"] {
border-radius: 25px;
height: 20px;opacity: 100%;}`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using JavaScript. Use onmouseover Event to change the opacity when mouse hover over the navbar. And use onfocus event to change the opacity permanently once it is dirty.

```
<input type="text" onfocus="dirtyStyle(this)">

<script>
function dirtyStyle(x) {
  x.style.opacity = ".6";
}
</script>
```